# How to make GET method request with header in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

I am trying to make a Get method request to a remote webpage and send header with request. My request got the correct header values and cookies but when i run this code I keep getting error below:

Could any one tell me how to fix this error and make proper Get method request? Should i import any libarary that I am missing ?Thanks in advance.

code:

```
import urllib,urllib2,re,xbmcplugin,xbmcgui,sys,os,xbmc,xbmcaddon
    import cookielib,requests,json 
    import requests 

def myfunction(url):

        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        resp = opener.open(url)

        resp2 = opener.open('http://www.awebsite.com/test/api.php')
        html_data = resp2.read()
        pattern = re.compile('"X-hello-data",\s?"(.*?)"')
        xhellodata = pattern.search(html_data).groups()[0]


        myheaders = {'Cookie' : cookies, 'User-Agent' : 'XBMC', 'Referer' : 'http://www.awebsite.com/main.php', 'X-hello-data' : xhellodata}

        itemurl = 'http://www.awebsite.com/ajax.php?season=winter&type=2&name=test'

        r = http.request('GET', itemurl, headers=myheaders)
        print r;

        itemurl2 = urllib.unquote(r.data)
        print 'valueofItemUrl2'
        print itemurl2;
```

error:

```
ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
- NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>
Error Contents: global name 'http' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\......\addon.py", line 703, in <module>
myfunction(url)
File "f:\.....\addon.py", line 636, in myfunction
r = http.request('GET', itemurl, headers=myheaders)
NameError: global name 'http' is not defined
-->End of Python script error report<--
```

Answer (score -1):

The error that you're getting in all of that mess is

> global name 'http' is not defined

If you look at your code, you never initialize http anywhere so it's clearly an undefined variable when you attempt to use it in the line:

```
r = http.request('GET', itemurl, headers=myheaders)
```

I would recommend using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) for your GET

```
r = requests.get(itemurl, headers=myheaders, cookies=cj)
print(r.text)
```

You can then parse the response any way that you would like.

I personally would use requests exclusively for what you're trying to do (not tested because you didn't post a real URL).

```
import requests
import json

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
response = requests.get('http://www.awebsite.com/test/api.php', cookies=cj)
xhellodata = response.headers.get('X-hello-data')

myheaders = {'Cookie' : cookies, 'User-Agent' : 'XBMC', 'Referer' : 'http://www.awebsite.com/main.php', 'X-hello-data' : xhellodata}

itemurl = 'http://www.awebsite.com/ajax.php?season=winter&type=2&name=test'

response = requests.get(itemurl, headers=myheaders, cookies=cj)
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your suggestion but i get value of r  =<Response [200]> instead of <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x107B2370>! I get this error :Error Contents: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data' when trying  print itemurl2; should add the cookie on header or should i do it your way ? i still cant get the required data back from my request. i only get <Response [200]> instead of json response!

Comment: I'll update my answer but you need to read the documentation at the link I posted to `requests`

Comment: okay but the thing is I *dont* have requests. Any tips for us who are stuck using builtin libraries??!?